# The same number of distinct elements and ones in the partitions of the number.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, integer-partitions

> For a given partition $\pi$ of the number $n$, let $A(\pi)$ denote the number of ones in $\pi$, and $B(\pi)$ the number of distinct parts in $\boldsymbol{\pi}$. 
> EXAMPLE: for the partition $\pi: 1+1+2+2+2+4$ we have $A(\pi)=2$ and $B(\pi)=3$. 
> Prove that $\sum_\pi A(\pi)=\sum_\pi B(\pi)$, where the summation is over all partitions of a fixed number $n$.

I know there is already a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3492372/show-that-the-number-of-1s-in-all-the-partitions-equals-the-sum-of-number-of-d), but the solution methods are a bit different, and I wanted to know if my approach is correct.

I tried to express each side of the identity using $P(k)$ which is the total number of partitions of the number $k$. $P(0)=1$ 
I got $$\sum_{\pi} A(\pi) = \sum_{i=1}^n i(P(n-i)-P(n-i-1))$$
where $i$ is the number of $1$'s in the partition, and
$P(n-i)-P(n-i-1)$ is number of partitions, of the remaining number $n-i$, without $1$'s. For example, for $n = 6$ and $i = 2$, we have $(1+1)(P(4)-P(3)) = 2 \cdot 2 = 4$, which corresponds to number of $1$'s in $4+1+1$ and $2+2+1+1$.

Also $$\sum_{\pi} B(\pi) = \sum_{i=1}^n P(n-i)$$
where $P(n-i)$ is the number of partitions containing at least one $i$. For example, for $n = 6$ and $i = 3$, we have the partitions $3+3$ and $3+2+1$.

However, I haven't been able to show that these sums are equal, that is
$$\sum_{i=1}^n i(P(n-i)-P(n-i-1)) = \sum_{i=1}^n P(n-i)$$

How can this be done? 
Thanks.

Comment: Look at, say, $n=3$; you get $P(2)-P(1)+2(P(1)-P(0))+3(P(0)-P(-1))$ which is $P(2)+(-P(1)+2P(1))+(-2P(0)+3P(0))-3P(-1)=P(2)+P(1)+P(0)$ since $P(-1)=0$. Can you see how the cancellation goes? Or, use "summation by parts".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @GerryMyerson wrote in the comment, the terms of the $\sum_{\pi} A(\pi) = \sum_{i=1}^n i(P(n-i)-P(n-i-1))$ cancel each other out, and one of each remains.